# Weird Javascript Anonymous function under Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, anonymous

```
<body>
   <section>
      <p id="status"></p>
      <button>Send</button>
   </section>
</body>
```

Above is the HTML code,and I add an event to the button with the above Javascript code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var status = document.querySelector('#status');
    var sendBtn = document.querySelector('button');
    sendBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        status.innerHTML='online'
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button it doesn't work (I use Google Chrome 27), but IE,Firefox and Ppera work well. I think the variable `status` is not defined in the anonymous function. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: have you looked into console? Are there any errors?

Comment: @antyrat NO,there is no error in the console

Comment: works normal for me under Chrome 27 http://jsfiddle.net/62sGZ/

Comment: weired,the opera,IE,Firefox work fine except chrome

Comment: does it work if change it to

document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML='online'

Comment: YES, it works if change it to  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML='online

Comment: btw ,in opera `status` is kinda reserved word: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp

Comment: yeah,I solve the problem, status is the reserved  word in chrome!Thanks to all !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,Finally I solve the problem.
status is a reserved word in the chrome.